# FORECAST function row by row (google-sheets)

Tags: google-sheets, forecast

I can successfully use the Google Sheets FORECAST function like this:

[image: FORECAST example 1]

However, due the shape and size of my data, what I really want to do is use it like this:

[image]

However, this throws a divide by zero error. So, either I'm doing it wrong (likely) or the function doesn't like swapping its x's & y's?

Any ideas on how to achieve this would be much appreciated.

Comment: If you already have the date, are you trying to forecast to the number ?

Comment: I just went ahead and tried to reproduce your problem but I couldn't both the first image and second one (transpose) seems to work fine for me. Giving the same results as you got. Could you share a sample sheet with that same example to see what's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't replicate the error as my google sheets the same values worked fine:

[image]

So, I have 2 options you can try:

- you can wrap the arrays with the `N()` function: `=forecast(F11,arrayformula(n(A12:E12)),arrayformula(n(A11:E11)))`
- make sure the values are well formatted: the values of the dates should be dates and the values of the numbers are numbers:

[image]

Let me know if any solution worked =)

Comment: Many thanks for this. 1) Wrapping the arrays with the n() function solved it. 2) On further inspection, I realised that one couple of my "date" cells was a simple string of "2020-07" rather than a proper date, so that was my first mistake! Thanks again.